# How to exchange order of numbers in multiple citations ([3-1] instead of [1-3])?

Tags: citing, natbib, multiple-citations

I use natbib with xepersian. I want to change the order of compressed references numbers from [1-3] to [3-1].

Comment: For numbers 1,2,3,4,5, `1--4` means `1` and the numbers between `1` and `4` starting from `1`... it is a range, and will contain the numbers `1,2,3,4` ... On the other hand: `4--1` range (in programming and possibly in math) should mean `4,5,1` ... I don't think it would be useful at all as a "citation range"...

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. As I should follow my institutional guidelines, It is important to present this range as [3--1] instead of [1--3]. The persian writing start from right to left, but the math and numbers present from left to right. The way that xepersian show the compressed reference as [1--3] in context from right to left is good-looking, but is in contradiction with conventional rules. Simply, I desire to represent this range of citations in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.
In **persian** text, you should to  use 
`\cite{1,2,3,4}` and in **latin** text you should to use `\lr{\cite{1,2,3,4}}`

Please see my sample:(I used the [alpha-persian](https://ctan.org/pkg/alpha-persian)  style.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=green!80!black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @mastersthesis{1,
        title={فضای توپولوژی},
        author={رضایی علی‌آباد,علی},
        key ={6},
        slabel = {1},
        school={شریف},
        journal={Kyungpook mathematical journal},
        pages={1163--1171},
        madadurltest={1},
        LANGUAGE =     {Persian},
        murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
        series = {second series},
        year = {2002},
        chapter={5},
        note ={یک یادداشت اختیاری},

    }

‌
@inbook{4,
  AUTHOR =  {نامداری,مهرداد and کوچک‌پور,عبدعلی},
  TITLE =  {مقدمه‌ای بر نظریه‌ی  اصولی مجموعه‌ها},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1394},
  MONTH =  {بهار},
  PAGES =  {39-43},
quotation={1},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
doi   = {322/511},
isbn = {978-600-141-173-1},
edition ={دوم},
series = {سری دوم},
number = {100},
chapter={5},
madadurltest={1},
 murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
publisher = {انتشارات دانشگاه چمران},
  note = {یک یادداشت اختیاری در این‌جا می‌توانید وارد کنید},
 address      = {آدرس منتشر کننده},
slabel = {$\checkmark\checkmark$},
}
@inbook{3,
    AUTHOR =  {مددپور, شاپور  and مددپور, محمدحسین and سایرین},
   slabel = {3},
    TITLE =  {همریختی و بروریختی در حلقه‌ها},
    JOURNAL =  {مجله‌ی گراف فارس},
    VOLUME =  {1},
    YEAR =  {1395},
    MONTH =  {بهار},
    PAGES =  {39-43},
    quotation={1},
    LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
    doi   = {01.1000/doi-0121},
    isbn = {123456789000},
    edition ={دوم},
    series = {سری دوم},
    number = {10},
    chapter={5},
    madadurltest={1},
    murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
    publisher = {انتشارات دل آهنگ},
    note = {یک یادداشت اختیاری در این‌جا می‌توانید وارد کنید},
    address      = {آدرس منتشر کننده},
}
@inbook{2,
   LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
    AUTHOR =  {مددپور, شاپور },
   slabel = {2},
    TITLE =  {همریختی و بروریختی در حلقه‌ها},
    JOURNAL =  {مجله‌ی گراف فارس},
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
     داریم:
\cite{1,2,3,4}
و همچنین
\lr{\cite{1,2,3,4}}

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha-persian}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Second edit:**
You should use `\TREE` command with this structure:

```
\newcommand{\RRLE}[1]{\setcitestyle{open={]},close={[}}\LRE{#1}\setcitestyle{open={[},close={]}}}
```

These are your `codes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=green!80!black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\settextfont{Yas}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @mastersthesis{1,
        title={فضای توپولوژی},
        author={رضایی علی‌آباد,علی},
        key ={6},
        slabel = {1},
        school={شریف},
        journal={Kyungpook mathematical journal},
        pages={1163--1171},
        madadurltest={1},
        LANGUAGE =     {Persian},
        murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
        series = {second series},
        year = {2002},
        chapter={5},
        note ={یک یادداشت اختیاری},

    }

‌
@inbook{4,
  AUTHOR =  {نامداری,مهرداد and کوچک‌پور,عبدعلی},
  TITLE =  {مقدمه‌ای بر نظریه‌ی  اصولی مجموعه‌ها},
  VOLUME =  {1},
  YEAR =  {1394},
  MONTH =  {بهار},
  PAGES =  {39-43},
quotation={1},
  LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
doi   = {322/511},
isbn = {978-600-141-173-1},
edition ={دوم},
series = {سری دوم},
number = {100},
chapter={5},
madadurltest={1},
 murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
publisher = {انتشارات دانشگاه چمران},
  note = {یک یادداشت اختیاری در این‌جا می‌توانید وارد کنید},
 address      = {آدرس منتشر کننده},
slabel = {$\checkmark\checkmark$},
}
@inbook{3,
    AUTHOR =  {مددپور, شاپور  and مددپور, محمدحسین and سایرین},
   slabel = {3},
    TITLE =  {همریختی و بروریختی در حلقه‌ها},
    JOURNAL =  {مجله‌ی گراف فارس},
    VOLUME =  {1},
    YEAR =  {1395},
    MONTH =  {بهار},
    PAGES =  {39-43},
    quotation={1},
    LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
    doi   = {01.1000/doi-0121},
    isbn = {123456789000},
    edition ={دوم},
    series = {سری دوم},
    number = {10},
    chapter={5},
    madadurltest={1},
    murl = {http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/},
    publisher = {انتشارات دل آهنگ},
    note = {یک یادداشت اختیاری در این‌جا می‌توانید وارد کنید},
    address      = {آدرس منتشر کننده},
}
@inbook{2,
   LANGUAGE =   {Persian},
    AUTHOR =  {مددپور, شاپور },
   slabel = {2},
    TITLE =  {همریختی و بروریختی در حلقه‌ها},
    JOURNAL =  {مجله‌ی گراف فارس},
}

\end{filecontents}



\newcommand{\RRLE}[1]{\setcitestyle{open={]},close={[}}\LRE{#1}}


\begin{document}
     داریم:
\cite{1,2,3,4}
و همچنین
\lr{\cite{1,2,3,4}}
اما با دستور جدید داریم:
\RRLE{\cite{1,2,3,4}}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{alpha-persian}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

And this is your `output`:

[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Previously I tried this, but the problem here is the numbers which not shown in Persian. Is there a solution to keep the order of presenation in "\lr{}" with Persian font.

Comment: Yes. Please see the second edit.

Comment: Tank you for your answer. Something catastrophic happens here with new command. If add a single citation after "citation range" the braces around the citation appears in reverse order.
Please append this line to the sample file:
ارجاع جدید پس از دستور جدید
\cite{1}.

Comment: You are right. so change `RRLE` command to this structure:
`\newcommand{\RRLE}[1]{\setcitestyle{open={]},close={[}}\LRE{#1}\setcitestyle{open={[},close={]}}}`

Comment: Heartily thank you for your efforts to solve this problem.

Comment: Still there is a little problem when using this solution. If insert punctuation marks after "citation range", an unwanted space inserted between closing brace and mark. Please add this line to the sample:
 `چند ارجاع از جمله \RRLE{\cite{1,2,3,4}}، می‌تواند به فاصله ناخواسته ختم شود
 \RRLE{\cite{1,2,3,4}}.‍`

Comment: Fortunately, It can be ride by adding `\unskip` at the end of command. So the right command looks like: 
`\newcommand{\RRLE}[1]{\setcitestyle{open={]},close={[}}\LRE{#1}\setcitestyle{open={[},close={]}}\unskip}`

Comment: @mohammad taqi jafari. Thanks a lot.